# How to to return most recent data using group by and order by

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.4

I have seen many posts but nothing is wokring. It seems group by always group the oldest one. I want to group the result and pick the most recent one. 
Here is my query

```
Message::whereIn('conversation_id',$msgs)
             ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc') 
             ->groupBy('conversation_id')
             ->with(array('last_sender'=>function($query){
                    $query->select('id','userName','profilePic', 'firstName','lastName');
              }))
            ->get();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this

```
Message::whereIn('conversation_id',$msgs)
             ->with(array('last_sender'=>function($query){
                    $query->select('id','userName','profilePic', 'firstName','lastName');
              }))
             ->orderBy('conversation_id', 'desc') 
             ->groupBy('conversation_id')
            ->get();
```

Comment: Awesome. But it would have been perfect if we can order by time. But anyways it works! Thank you soo much...

Comment: You are welcome ,pleas close your question by accepting my answer :)

Comment: sure I tired but you know it takes five mins ;) Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

To order by time, try this one:

```
Message::select(DB::raw('MAX(created_at) AS max_created_at'))
             ->whereIn('conversation_id',$msgs)
             ->orderBy('max_created_at', 'desc') 
             ->groupBy('conversation_id')
             ->with(array('last_sender'=>function($query){
                    $query->select('id','userName','profilePic', 'firstName','lastName');
              }))
            ->get();
```